# Wait for a "3rd party" element to be appended to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dom

Let's say we're writing a user script which interacts with a 3rd party site we don't control. We want to open a menu, so we trigger a click on the button and then wait 10ms before accessing the menu (which is appended to the document after the click), like this:

```
$button = $('#button');
$button.trigger('click');
setTimeout(function() {
    //access the menu
}, 10);
```

This works, because it takes less than 10ms for the 3rd party site's handler to appended the menu to the DOM once the button is clicked. But it feels like bad code. Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Better question for StackOverflow.

Comment: @MikeBrant I wasn't sure since my code actually works, it just doesn't "feel" like good code, which is sort of not a "programming" problem, it seems like more of a "coding style" problem.

Comment: I think it could be up for interpretation, but the way a look at it is that you need to write a bit of code, that does not yet exist that needs to listen for the `onload` event for the particular DOM element you are interested in and then trigger click on it.

Comment: @MikeBrant True. The alternate interpretation could be that in lots of great answers on the site, people delete some code and write new code in a way the differs functionally, like the answer below, to demonstrate a better way of writing the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a perfect job for [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```
new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    this.disconnect();
    // access the menu
    ........
}).observe($('.immediate-parent-of-the-menu')[0], {childList: true});

$button = $('#button');
$button.trigger('click');
```

The simplest case above works as-is if the menu is added in one mutation, otherwise you'd have to check each of the `mutations` array elements for `addedNodes`.